# php - Right Angle Triangle

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am new in PHP programming.Can anyone explain this code step by step?

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
 for($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
    echo "*";
 }
 echo"<br>";
}
```

Comment: loop 5 times, then loop n times the iteration value, the output explains it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php  For loops are in most languages and almost always have the same structure.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? Did you already read some tutorial and PHP and descriptions how to do loops? Other than that you always have the references: https://php.net/echo and https://php.net/for (you can put any keyword and you will get redirected to the relevant documentation).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I see tutorial and i know how to loop , in this code, i cant undrestand order of the code execution. i cant understand which code execute first , which code execute next and ...

Comment: Hook up a debugger... xdebug is great with IDEs, then you can see the code execute line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop ($i) goes from 1 to 5. You can think of this as the rows of output in this case.

Within each row, the inner loop ($j) prints out a quantity of $i asterisks. So in row 1, it outputs `*`, row 2, `**`, and so on.

Before moving on to the next row, it prints out a line break. So the final output will be something like:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```